# JSON Parsing Error in Java Spring Function

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, serialization

I am trying to create a function that generates a question and stores it into the database using Java Spring. I'm uncertain whether the issue lies in the JSON or the structure of my code. (I've provided both below.)

Here's the structure I'm currently using:

**Question Service Implementation**

```
@Service
public class QuestionServiceImpl implements QuestionService {
    private final QuestionRepository questionRepository;
    private final ConversionService conversionService;

    public QuestionServiceImpl(QuestionRepository questionRepository, ConversionService conversionService) {
        this.questionRepository = questionRepository;
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
    }

    @Override
    public QuestionOutput createQuestion(QuestionInput input) {
        Question question = conversionService.convert(input, Question.class);
        Question savedQuestion = questionRepository.save(question);
        return conversionService.convert(savedQuestion, QuestionOutput.class);
}
```

**Question Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/question")
public class QuestionController {

    private final QuestionService questionService;

    public QuestionController(QuestionService questionService) {
        this.questionService = questionService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<QuestionOutput> createQuestion(@RequestBody QuestionInput input){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(questionService.createQuestion(input), HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
}
```

**Question Output**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class QuestionOutput {
    private String id;
    private String questionBody;
    private Difficulty difficulty;
    private Category category;
    private Quiz quiz;
    private List<Answer> answers;
}
```

**Question Input**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class QuestionInput {
    private Answer answer;
    private Difficulty difficulty;
    private Category category;
    private String questionBody;
    private Quiz quiz;
    private List<Answers> answers;
}
```

**Question Input to Question entity**

```
@Component
public class QuestionInputToQuestion implements Converter<QuestionInput, Question> {
    @Override
    public Question convert(QuestionInput source) {
        return Question.builder()
                .questionBody(source.getQuestionBody())
                .answers(source.getAnswers())
                .category(source.getCategory())
                .quiz(source.getQuiz())
                .difficulty(source.getDifficulty())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Question to Question Output**

```
@Component
public class QuestionToQuestionOutput implements Converter<Question, QuestionOutput> {
    @Override
    public QuestionOutput convert(Question source) {
        return QuestionOutput
                .builder()
                .id(source.getId())
                .questionBody(source.getQuestionBody())
                .difficulty(source.getDifficulty())
                .category(source.getCategory())
                .quiz(source.getQuiz())
                .answers(source.getAnswers())
                .build();
    }

}
```

**JSON**

```json
{
  "answer": {
    "id": "string",
    "answer": "string",
    "isRight": true,
    "question": {
      "id": "string",
      "questionBody": "string",
      "difficulty": "string",
      "category": "string",
      "quiz": "string",
      "answers": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },
  "difficulty": {
    "id": "string",
    "difficulty": "string",
    "questions": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "questionBody": "string",
        "difficulty": "string",
        "category": "string",
        "quiz": "string",
        "answers": [
          "string"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "category": {
    "id": "string",
    "categoryName": "string",
    "questions": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "questionBody": "string",
        "difficulty": "string",
        "category": "string",
        "quiz": "string",
        "answers": [
          "string"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "questionBody": "string",
  "quiz": {
    "id": "string",
    "user": {
      "id": "string",
      "username": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "password": "string",
      "permissions": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "permissions": "string",
          "users": [
            "string"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "quizzes": [
        "string"
      ]
    },
    "questions": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "questionBody": "string",
        "difficulty": "string",
        "category": "string",
        "quiz": "string",
        "answers": [
          "string"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "answer": "string",
      "isRight": true,
      "question": {
        "id": "string",
        "questionBody": "string",
        "difficulty": "string",
        "category": "string",
        "quiz": "string",
        "answers": [
          "string"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I make a request with this is the error I get

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.quizproject.db.entities.Difficulty` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('string')]
```

I know it's because of `"difficulty": "string"`, but I don't know how to change the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide some details on how you've defined the Difficulty class? Specifically, have you included a constructor or factory method that accepts a String argument for Difficulty? (`public Difficulty(String difficulty) {...}`)

Comment: I have used lombok and the annotations `@Builder, @NoArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor`.

Comment: You can keep the Lombok annotations while adding a constructor that accepts a string argument for **difficulty**, which would allow Spring to deserialise the JSON correctly. (`public Difficulty(String difficulty) { this.difficulty = difficulty; }`)

Comment: It worked, however will that link the difficulty to the question in the database?